# bash: mongo: command not found

Tags: mongodb

I installed mongodb on my system, but when I go to bin directory using Git and type mongo, this happens.

[image]

What shall I do?

Comment: run `ls` and see what is in the folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you're using git bash, use the following command

```
$ ./mongo
```

Comment: I get this error :- ./mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.7
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2017-08-18T08:12:04.236+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2017-08-18T08:12:04.236+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed

Comment: Looks like you don't have mongo server running, run `mongod`

Comment: looks like mongodb isn't running locally, can you confirm that mongod is running?

Comment: Do i have to set a path for this folder in my system variables ?

Comment: You just need to start the `mongod.exe` but make sure you have a `c:/data/db` folder

Comment: Executing "./mongo" command gives the following Error:
bash: ./mongo: No such file or directory

Answer (score 8):

The problem can be solve if you add MongoDB path in the system variables:

Go to this path "**Control Panel\System and Security\System**" on the left you should see some options click on "**Advanced system settings**" after this click on "**Environment Variables**" at the System variables should be one option "**Path**" click that option and "**Edit**" it, add "**New**" variable on this system, in my case, is "**C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin**" and save this change.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same problem and did this to solve it. I hope it helps (late, but to be sure it is answered).

Open GitBash and type the following:

1) cd.. // to go to the root directory.

2) touch .bash_profile // creates a hidden file to set up the shortcut

3) notepad .bash_profile // this opens that hidden file with notepad. You can also do it with VIM if you want to master you command console skills...

4) paste these two command lines:

alias mongod="/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/4.0/bin/mongod.exe"

alias mongo="/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/4.0/bin/mongo.exe"

*!!! Check that your files are also in the same route as these. If not, modify what's needed. Mind the space between "\ Files" because this gave trouble too. You may need to change the version in case you don't have 4.0.*

5) Save the file. Close Notepad.

6) At Gitbash again: CRTL + C, and close the console.

7) Open Gitbash again, go to the root, and type: mongo --version. If you see something like: MongoDB Shell version v4.0.10... you've been successful (see image). If not, check the route of the document you've put into the bash profile, and be sure to fully restart the bash console after.

[Mongo install success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkivz.png)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use mongosh intead of mongo.
This solved my problem using docker

Answer (score 0):

In later versions of this, you have to download mongo shell. Once you downloaded if zip extracts the files and moved folder to your program's folder. Renamed the folder mongosh. Copy the path and added to your environment variables path. it should look like this C:\Program Files\mongosh\bin. Next, if you haven't done so already. Create data folder in your root directory in my case windows c drive. Create a subfolder in the data folder called db. make sure this folder is in the root directory and not in the program's folder. Once this is done, close all the prompt windows and run again mongod and again run now not mongo but mongosh, and it will allow you to type in your code. I had to delete my previous created data folder that i created previous to installation of MongoDB hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I will add to this, in case others had my error.  I set the paths in System and everything, but got the same error after following the answers above in my VSCode terminal.  I found that if I ran the command from Git bash instead of VSCode terminal, I did not get an error.  Make sure you are using Git bash.

Answer (score 0):

check the path

```
mongod.cfg
mongod.exe
mongod.pdb
**mongos.exe**
mongos.pdb
```

despit adding alias mongo="/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/4.0/bin/**mongo.exe**"

it should be alias mongo="/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/4.0/bin/**mongos.exe**"

Comment: mongos is the sharding service, instead of the concerned mongo shell.